# How to get all diagnoal elements in a matrix?

Tags: matrix, prolog, diagonal

I'd like to write a function that determines all the diagonal elements in a matrix are same.

For instance:

```
?-diagonal([[1,2,3,4],
            [2,1,5,6],
            [6,2,1,9],
            [8,7,5,1]]).
  true.
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your question doesn't match your title: get != check they are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Question solved...

```
diagonal([],_,_).
   diagonal([Head|Tail],Index,Value),
   nth0(Index,Head,Value),
   IndexNext is Index+1,
   diagonal(tail,IndexNext,Value).
```

Test:

```
?- diagonal([[1,2,3],
             [5,1,6],
             [9,3,1]],0,X).
   X=1.
```

Comment: Don't you need to end the second line with :- ? Also, shouldn't tail be Tail on the last line?